# percentage change for all columns in a row except one

Tags: r

ciao guys,

i have the following `dataframe`

```
  obj <- data.frame (degree2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
      yr = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997),
      degree = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0), degree3 = c(1, 1, 6, 7, 5, 1, 0, 0)
   )
```

what I would like to do is to create the percentage change for the variables `degree` `degree2` `degree3`
per year. Note that my real dataframe is quite long.

I guess the code must by something like in the sense of: "for every row compute percentual change for all variables except `yr`

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `mutate` with `across` after `arrange` by 'yr' (in case not ordered) and create new columns by modifying the `.names` in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
obj <- obj %>% 
   arrange(yr) %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with('degree'),
           ~ 100 *c(0, diff(.))/., .names = '{.col}_perc_change'))
```

---

Or if we need to do the difference from the next to the current, use `lead` and `-`

```
obj <- obj %>% 
  arrange(yr) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('degree'),
       ~ 100 * (lead(.) - .)/., .names = '{.col}_perc_change'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your solution would fit great to my issue.. Unfortunately I have a data frame consisting of 100 columns. As try to apply this code, it only computes the percentage change for the column placed in  starts_with('  ') .. do you know how to handle this ?

Comment: @ akrun. Could you please check my solution. Now it is with percentage change. But why are the original values are NA now?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Update with correct function to calculate the percentage change:**

Thanks to ThoamslsCoding:

The function to calculate:
Divide `x` by the `lag` of `x` substract `1` and then multiple by `100`

```
pct_change <- function(x) {(x/lag(x) -1) * 100}

obj %>% 
  mutate(across(c(degree2, degree, degree3), pct_change, .names = "pct_change_{.col}"))
```

Output:

```
  degree2   yr degree degree3 pct_change_degree2 pct_change_degree pct_change_degree3
1       1 1990      1       1                 NA                NA                 NA
2       1 1991      1       1                0.0                 0                0.0
3       2 1992      1       6              100.0                 0              500.0
4       2 1993      2       7                0.0               100               16.7
5       3 1994      1       5               50.0               -50              -28.6
6       3 1995      1       1                0.0                 0              -80.0
7       4 1996      0       0               33.3              -100             -100.0
8       4 1997      0       0                0.0               NaN                NaN
```

**First answer: not correct:**

```
# function to calculate percentage change
pct_change <- function(x) {x/lag(x)}

obj %>% 
  mutate(across(c("degree2", "degree", "degree3"), pct_change))
```

output:

```
   degree2   yr degree degree3 degree2_perc_change degree_perc_change degree3_perc_change
1      NA 1990     NA      NA                 0.0                  0                 0.0
2    1.00 1991    1.0   1.000                 0.0                  0                 0.0
3    2.00 1992    1.0   6.000                50.0                  0                83.3
4    1.00 1993    2.0   1.167                 0.0                 50                14.3
5    1.50 1994    0.5   0.714                33.3               -100               -40.0
6    1.00 1995    1.0   0.200                 0.0                  0              -400.0
7    1.33 1996    0.0   0.000                25.0               -Inf                -Inf
8    1.00 1997    NaN     NaN                 0.0                NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: I think OP wants percentage of changes

Comment: It seems the percentage values not correct

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. After some sleep and with fresh mind I got behind the problem. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
> (obj[-1, -2] / obj[-nrow(obj), -2] - 1) * 100
    degree2 degree    degree3
2   0.00000      0    0.00000
3 100.00000      0  500.00000
4   0.00000    100   16.66667
5  50.00000    -50  -28.57143
6   0.00000      0  -80.00000
7  33.33333   -100 -100.00000
8   0.00000    NaN        NaN
```

---

or we can bind columns like below

```
perc <- (obj[-1, -2] / obj[-nrow(obj), -2] - 1) * 100
perc <- setNames(perc, paste0(names(perc), "_perc_change"))
obj[rownames(perc), names(perc)] <- perc
```

which gives

```
> obj
  degree2   yr degree degree3 degree2_perc_change degree_perc_change
1       1 1990      1       1                  NA                 NA
2       1 1991      1       1             0.00000                  0
3       2 1992      1       6           100.00000                  0
4       2 1993      2       7             0.00000                100
5       3 1994      1       5            50.00000                -50
6       3 1995      1       1             0.00000                  0
7       4 1996      0       0            33.33333               -100
8       4 1997      0       0             0.00000                NaN
  degree3_perc_change
1                  NA
2             0.00000
3           500.00000
4            16.66667
5           -28.57143
6           -80.00000
7          -100.00000
8                 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R using `lapply` -

```
cols <- setdiff(names(obj), 'yr')
obj[paste0('perc_', cols)] <- lapply(obj[cols],function(x) c(0, diff(x))/x * 100)
obj

#  degree2   yr degree degree3 perc_degree2 perc_degree perc_degree3
#1       1 1990      1       1      0.00000           0      0.00000
#2       1 1991      1       1      0.00000           0      0.00000
#3       2 1992      1       6     50.00000           0     83.33333
#4       2 1993      2       7      0.00000          50     14.28571
#5       3 1994      1       5     33.33333        -100    -40.00000
#6       3 1995      1       1      0.00000           0   -400.00000
#7       4 1996      0       0     25.00000        -Inf         -Inf
#8       4 1997      0       0      0.00000         NaN          NaN
```